# $ \operatorname{Im}(A)\subseteq \operatorname{Ker}(B)\Rightarrow (AB)^{2}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let $A,B:V\rightarrow V$. If $ \operatorname{Im}(A)\subseteq  \operatorname{Ker}(B)$ then $(AB)^{2}=0$

Intuitively I can see why this holds, but I cannot find the way to prove it.

Comment: This situation is typical in cohomology.

Comment: $(AB)^2=ABAB$ and $im(AB)\subseteq im(A)\subseteq Ker (B)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$(AB)^2=(AB)(AB)=A(BA)B.$$
Can you compute $BA$ from the hypothesis?

Comment: $BA=0$ because whole image of A is in kernel of B?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that.